# how to use 3rd axis input in unity?

Tags: unity, javascript, joystick

I'm currently using a xbox 360 controller on my windows 10 computer. I've been trying to find how to use the LT and RT buttons on my controller to shoot and aim. Can some one give me an example on how to receive and use input with these buttons? I am using javascript, so it would be helpful to have it in that programming language!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have no controller to test, but this seems to be the same question: [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/17669/setting-up-game-pad.html). Once you set the controller up you should be able to use it as other input devices [Using Input Axis](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly reference *axis* via programming. The `InputManager` requires you to set them up, manually. You can then reference the axis via their `string` identifiers.

[image: LT, RT and "LT+RT" set up as axis (9th, 10th and 3rd, respectively) in the Unity Input Manager.]

Once set up like this, you can use `Input.GetAxis([Name])`. To grab **LT** (9th Axis), given the above setup, you would use `Input.GetAxis("LeftTrigger")`.